# type does not provide a call operator

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this function, `order`, which returns `vector<Node*>`

```
vector<Node*> order(vector<string> nodes, vector<pair<string, string>> dependencies) {
             Graph graph = buildGraph(nodes, dependencies);
             vector<Node*> order = buildOrder(graph.getNodes());
             return order;
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
vector<Node*> order2 = order(nodes, deps);
```

However, the compiler gives this error:

```
error: type 'std::__1::vector<Node *, std::__1::allocator<Node *> >' does not provide a call operator
        vector<Node*> order2 = order(nodes, deps);
                               ^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

What is going wrong? `'std::__1::vector<Node *, std::__1::allocator<Node *> >'` seems to suggest that there is a `vector<Node*, <Node*>>` or something going on, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: The compiler sees `order` as an object of type `std::__1::vector<Node *, std::__1::allocator<Node *> >`. So when you try to call the function, the compiler looks for a call operator on this object. Check how you declare the order function or any conflicting declaration. Also you should put a space between the 2 `>` in the 2nd parameter or the order function. This could be interpreted as a `>>` operator.

Comment: @BenjaminT thanks - I had declared something with `order` before this. To your second point, doesn't c++11 suppot `>>` with no spaces? Is it just not good style to omit the space inbetween the two `>`s?

Comment: @BenjaminT This question is tagged as c++11, which has no problem with `>>`.

Comment: @LeibnizMan My bad I forgot the C++11 tag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell without your posting more complete code, but consider the following:

```
int order(int j, int k)
{   
    return 3;
}   

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char order;

    // order(2, 3);                                                
}
```

This code builds fine. However, uncommenting

```
    // order(2, 3);
```

causes it to fail, as within `main`, `order` is a character, not a function. From the error message, it looks like you might have some similar problem.

Comment: I would mention, that it could be fixed by calling `order` as `::order`.

Comment: @Zereges That's a very good point - thanks. OTOH, maybe it would be more readable just to name things distinctly, no?